# How get class img elements into form and show into my Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to take some elements (class img) from a form(id).

My Html:

```
<form id="slider" onclick="show()">
            <img class="img" src="/images/simpson1.png"/><br>
            <img class="img" src="/images/simpson2.png"/><br>
            <img class="img" src="/images/simpson2.png"/><br>
        </form>

<div id="immagini">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
```

and i want that at the click of images(into form),recall a function that show image into my array [].

My JS:

```
  function show() {
        var imgArray = new Array();
        imgArray = new Image();
        /*-------------------------------*/
        imgArray[0] = "/images/Immagine1.png";
        imgArray[1] = "/images/simpson2.png";
        imgArray[2] = "/images/immagine1.png";

        var img = document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByClassName("img");

        switch(img)  
    {
        case 0: document.getElementById("immagini").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = imgArray[0]; break;
        case 1: document.getElementById("immagini").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = imgArray[1]; break;
        case 2: document.getElementById("immagini").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = imgArray[2]; break;

    }
```

But I don't could,how can I do?!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged it using jQuery and I assume you want to show the clicked image in the `#immagini img`.

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    //register a click handler to the img elements under the form with id slider
    $('#slider img').click(function () {
        //set the clicked images source as the source for the image under #immagini
        $('#immagini img').attr('src', this.src);
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8TJDA/)

Comment: Ok perfect,but i would that function Show() show images's Array[],not show images of form.

Comment: @ Arun P Johny I mean Array[] in my Js.I want that images of my Array to show the screen when I click on the images of html

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it with Jquery this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form#slider img.img').click(function () {

        $('div#immagini img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));

    });


});
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3g9XT/1/)**

**UPDATE**

if you want to load image src from a local array you can check this fiddle:

[DEMO With Array](http://jsfiddle.net/js6C9/)

and here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form#slider img.img').click(function () {

            //$('div#immagini img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
        show(0);

        });

  });
```

Here is `show()` :

```
function show(img) {
        var imgArray = new Array();
        imgArray = new Image();
        /*-------------------------------*/
        imgArray[0] = "http://www.genfavicon.com/images/germany.png";
        imgArray[1] = "http://www.genfavicon.com/images/ingles.gif";
        imgArray[2] = "http://www.genfavicon.com/images/espanol.gif";

        //var img = $('.img');

        switch(img)  
    {
        case 0:
            $('div#immagini img').attr('src', imgArray[0]); 
            break;
        case 1: 
            $('div#immagini img').attr('src', imgArray[1]); 
            break;
        case 2: 
            $('div#immagini img').attr('src', imgArray[2]); 
            break;

    }


    }
```

Comment: Ok perfect,but i would that function Show() show images's Array[],not show images of form.

Comment: Which array you mean?

Comment: @ Ehsan Sajjad I mean Array[] in my Js.I want that images of my Array to show the screen when I click on the images of html

Comment: @Jack_812 if you provide JsFiddle what you tried i can help you more easily

Comment: @Jack_812 check updated answer and fiddle demo, i am sure you will get your answer now

Comment: @Jack_812 mark it answer and vote up as appreciation if you got out of the problem